# error name 'dtype' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy

I try to compile this code but I get this errror :

```
NameError: name 'dtype' is not defined
```

Here is the python code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import missingno as msno
from functools import partial
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)


if dtype(data.OPP_CREATION_DATE)=="datetime64[ns]":
    print("OPP_CREATION_DATE is of datetime type")
else:
    print("warning: the type of OPP_CREATION_DATE is not datetime, please fix this")
```

Any idea please to help me to resolve this problem? 
Thank you

Comment: what is `data` in this snippet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written by Amr Keleg,

> If `data` is a pandas dataframe then you can check the type of a
>   column as follows:
>  `df['colname'].dtype` or `df.colname.dtype`

In that case you need e.g.

```
df['colname'].dtype ==  np.dtype('datetime64')
```

or

```
df.colname.dtype ==  np.dtype('datetime64')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `type` instead of `dtype`.

`type` is a built-in function of python -
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

On the other hand, If `data` is a pandas dataframe then you can check the type of a column as follows:
`df['colname'].dtype` or `df.colname.dtype`

Comment: Also for python2: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#type

Answer (score 2):

I have just realized that I could have used:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype, is_numeric_dtype
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question asked here, it seems you were trying to solve a related but different problem.